# How to create a stored function in MongoDB using the PHP driver

Tags: php, mongodb, stored-functions

I'm trying to make a design decision.

I'm not well acquainted with either MongoDB or its PHP driver but I'm intrigued by the JavaScript syntax of the stored functions that mongodb use.

**Can you tell me whether there is a way to create MongoDB stored functions using PHP?**

My reference for creating mongodb stored functions: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/jstests/storefunc.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are referencing [server-side functions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Storingfunctionsserverside).

Creating / updating a server-side function is as easy as updating the `system.js` collection:

```
db.system.js.save( { _id : "foo" , value : function( x , y ){ return x + y; } } );
```

The problem here is really "using" the server-side functions. First you have to write some kind of awkward update/insert statements. Second, these are not stored procedures. They are not compiled for speed with the intent of running them on the server.

If you use a server-side function for querying it won't use indexes for anything inside of that function. Plus it will use the `eval` feature under the hood which can lock up your DB.

Also, there are no triggers, so you can't use these for triggers either.

Overall, there is not a lot of use for server-side functions, which is probably why they get 3 paragraphs in the docs.

If you need advanced query functions look at the new Aggregation Framework. If you're looking for some form of triggers, you will have to roll your own. If you're looking for stored procedures, these are really not it.

Comment: Hm. If it's such a mess why does it actually exist? Is there any scenario where only server-side function can be used to solve a problem?

Comment: I think it's one of those things that was created when they *thought* it could be the next stored procedure. But the dream was really dashed by the fact that they can only have one instance of the javascript interpreter at a time. Worth remembering that MongoDB is only a couple of years old and they don't have enough people to really update the docs.

Comment: Just one  more thing: I read on **mapReduce** Are all of the fallbacks you describe applied to **mapReduce** as well?

Comment: A MongoDB instance can only run one Map/Reduce at a time. (*again only one javascript engine*) This is one of the big drivers for the Aggregation Framework from 2.1.

Comment: Thank you. I found an alternative way of doing what I aimed using the mapReduce: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15517/7652 by storing a closure in the document :)

Comment: When you use the mongo command-line client and define a function, is it stored as a server-side function, or in the memory of the client?  I ask because it it's in the client, it would be just as good to store JS functions in PHP strings to send when needed.